# How to use starts with condtion in qweb xml in odoo

Tags: xml, odoo-9, odoo-10, qweb

I would like to check if the variable is starts with the given string in qweb xml in odoo 9

Ex:

```
<t t-if="'CGST' in taxdetail.name ">
     <t t-esc="taxdetail.name" />
    </t>

 " like method"

<t t-if="'CGST' like '%taxdetail.name%' ">
    <t t-esc="taxdetail.name" />
 </t>
```

I have tried these methods. but i am getting  qweb error meassage.
                                                  Thanks,
                                                  Anand.

Comment: I don't have idea it will work or not but you can try,
create a method inside of whichever module's report you are created make sure that method returns boolean value,
in a condition of QWeb you can call that method and pass the values, that method returns boolean, so it's much easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just try below code

```
<t t-if="'CGST' == taxdetail.name[:4]" >
  <t t-esc="taxdetail.name" />
</t>
```

Comment: My Code:

 <t t-if="'CGST' == taxdetail.name[:4]">
           <t t-set="cgst_amt" t-value="cgst_amt+taxdetail.amount"/>
          </t>
Error:
 Error: QWeb2: Error evaluating template: SyntaxError: expected expression, got ':'

Comment: This is the code `<span t-if = "'20' == o.get('date')[:2]" t-esc="o.get('date')[:2]"/> ` i tried on now. working fine.